# Apprentice nephi wouldn't give the quest

Tags: world-of-warcraft

[image]

I am level 79 and would like to go to Halls of reflection but [Apprentice Nephi](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Apprentice_Nelphi) wouldn't give the [quest to do the attunement](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Quest:Inside_the_Frozen_Citadel),

We have also lvl 80 in party without attunemet and no **!** ether....

**Is there a quest before? Why apprentice Nephi wouldn't give the quest?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have figured it out myself so I went some time ago into [Forge of Souls](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Forge_of_Souls) and was given [quest (Echoes of Tortured Souls) that is 'higher up](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Quest:Echoes_of_Tortured_Souls)' in the chain this is why I couldn't take the prerequisite...

Comment: I'm surprised attunement is still a thing for old content.

Comment: @Powerlord This quest is not an attunement and never was; it's just an optional breadcrumb quest.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Still is as I can't get into Halls of reflection, I can get into Pit of Saron though, but doing instance does not attune you to Halls without quest...